# Find Beta Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Find the matrix $B$ for the transformation $A = \begin{bmatrix} 
> 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ in the basis $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$.

Am I overcomplicating this? Do I just put the basis into its own $2 \times 2$ matrix and then use the formula $S^{-1}AS$? 
I feel like I know how to do this, but want to make sure I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: "The matrix B" (beta or whatever)? What is that, anyway?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Use the formula for the transition from one basis to another

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).
I have tried to improve the readability of your question. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the transformation from basis

$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

to the standard basis is

$$v_S=Sv_B=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}v_B$$

thus given in the standard basis

$$w_S=Av_S$$

in the new basis we have

$$Sw_B=ASv_B\implies w_B=S^{-1}ASv_B$$

Can you follow these steps? What is not clear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\beta = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$ and $\gamma$ be the standard basis.  Then
\begin{align}
B &= [\mathsf{L}_A]_\beta \\
&= [\mathsf{Id}]_\gamma^\beta A [\mathsf{Id}]_\beta^\gamma \\
&= ([\mathsf{Id}]_\beta^\gamma)^{-1} A [\mathsf{Id}]_\beta^\gamma \\
&= \left( \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 4 \\ 5 & -7 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}